# matplotlib long legend name

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I have a following code which produces a graph -

```
# imports specific to the plots in this example
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

resultsDirectory='results'

outputFile=resultsDirectory+".pdf"
axisLabelFontSize=16
borderWidth=0.0

# Twice as wide as it is tall.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Set up the Grid
[i.set_linewidth(borderWidth) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]


unsatX=[680,2775,3821,680,4073,941,1202,1463]
unsatY=[1,1,1,4,1,2,2,2]
paretoX=[680, 1203,  1726,  4870]
paretoY=[10,7, 4,1]
satX=[4870,680,1727,1726,1203,680]
satY=[1,13,7,4,7,10]
typeX=[680, 1727]
typeY=[13, 7]
leftX=[680]
leftY=[12]

c = np.rec.fromarrays([paretoX, paretoY], names='x,y')
c.sort()
paretoX=c.x
paretoY=c.y

markrsz=8
l4, = plt.plot(paretoX, paretoY, '#000000', lw=2, label='Pareto Curve(unfolding, period locality)',markersize=markrsz,zorder = 10)
l1, = plt.plot(satX, satY, 'bo', label='Sat Points',markersize=markrsz,zorder = 10)
l2, = plt.plot(unsatX, unsatY, 'ro',marker='s',label='Unsat Points',markersize=markrsz,zorder = 10)
l5, = plt.plot(leftX, leftY, 'gp',label='Proc. count pareto points',markersize=markrsz)
l6, = plt.plot(typeX, typeY, 'w*',label='Modulo pareto points',markersize=markrsz,zorder=10)


leg=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.,-0.200, 1., 1.102), loc=3, numpoints=1,
       ncol=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0., fancybox=True, shadow=True,prop={'size':axisLabelFontSize})

rect = leg.get_frame()
rect.set_facecolor('#cccccc') # a grayscale intensity
#leg.set_frame_on(False)

latency=[680,2775,4870, 680,3821,4868, 680,1727,4341,4864, 680,1203,1726,1203, 680,4073,4334,4595,4856, 941,1202,1463,1724]
processor=[1, 1, 1,13, 1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7,10,1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

ax.set_xlabel('Period',size=axisLabelFontSize,labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Processors',size=axisLabelFontSize,labelpad=10)
ax.set_xlim(0, max(latency)+100)
ax.set_ylim(0, max(processor)+1)

# Set Border width zero
[i.set_linewidth(0) for i in ax.spines.itervalues()]

gridLineWidth=0.1
ax.set_axisbelow(False)
gridlines = ax.get_xgridlines()+ax.get_ygridlines()
#ax.set_axisbelow(True)

plt.setp(gridlines, 'zorder', 5)

ax.yaxis.grid(True, linewidth=gridLineWidth, linestyle='-', color='0.6',alpha='0.3')
ax.xaxis.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

fig.savefig(outputFile, format="pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

The legends in the plot get messed up.
Could someone tell me how do i fix a long legend entry which overwrites into area of other entry? What would be ideal if, I could do 3 legend entries in first row and two legend entries in the second row.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "fix a long legend name"

Comment: i mean it is over-writing in another legend's area.

Comment: the following modification to the code solved my problem temporarily - 

`leg=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.,-0.350, 1., 1.102), loc=3, numpoints=1, ncol=2   , borderaxespad=0., fancybox=True, shadow=True,prop={'size':axisLabelFontSize})`

Comment: @Raj You should post that as an answer.  You have hit a bit of mpl that is not as convenient as it could be.

Comment: @tcaswell sorry I didn't get, what is mpl?

Comment: @Raj, Sorry, mpl -> matplotlib.  Just a bit of lazy abbreviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the workaround found by the question author, a possibility is to add new lines for long labels:

```
...
l4, = plt.plot(paretoX, paretoY, '#000000', lw=2, 
    label='Pareto Curve \n(unfolding, period locality)',markersize=markrsz,zorder = 10)
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following modification to the code also solved my problem -

```
leg=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.,-0.350, 1., 1.102), loc=3, numpoints=1, ncol=2 , borderaxespad=0., fancybox=True, shadow=True,prop={'size':axisLabelFontSize})
```